# Nested EventHandler callbacks: when all are finished?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I try to integrate the AsanaNet in my project (https://github.com/acron0/AsanaNet) and have a general problem with nested EventHandler callbacks.

The query of the data works without problems. I just don't know when all EventHandler/task are completed, because there are several foreach loops with asynchronous callbacks. While all users are queried from workspace2, the users form workspace1 aren't finished.

When do I know when all users from all workspaces are loaded?

example with the mentioned AsanaNet:

```
asanaConn.GetWorkspaces(asanaWorkspaces =>
{
    foreach (AsanaWorkspace asanaWorkspace in asanaWorkspaces)
    {
        asanaConn.GetUsersInWorkspace(asanaWorkspace, asanaUsers =>
        {
            foreach (AsanaUser asanaUser in asanaUsers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("asanaUser: " + asanaUser.Name);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Callback:

```
public void GetTasksInWorkspace(AsanaWorkspace arg1,  AsanaUser arg2, AsanaCollectionResponseEventHandler callback)
{
    var request = GetBaseRequest(AsanaFunction.GetFunction(Function.GetTasksInWorkspace), arg1, arg2);
    request.Go((o, h) => PackAndSendResponseCollection<AsanaTask>(o, callback), ErrorCallback);
}
```

Comment: Method looks synchronous. So after `asanaConn.GetWorkspaces` executed everything is loaded isn't it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes and no. All => are  asynchronous callbacks. That means, the code inside =>{} is called when data is loaded.After asanaConn.GetWorkspaces the code is synchronous. But  asanaConn.GetUsersInWorkspace is called multiple times (foreach) and each asanaConn.GetUsersInWorkspace callback can be completed at some time.

Comment: Post the declaration of those methods. I mean signature

Comment: Added to the question. Thanks so far for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Either I have always overlooked it or now the async methods can be synchronized with a Wait();

So my problem is solved.

https://github.com/acron0/AsanaNet#asananet

```
asana.GetMe(o =>
{
    var user = o as AsanaUser;
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + user.Name);
}).Wait();   <---------------
```